# c# unity error can't flip my submarine on its y axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, flip

This has been an issue for a week now. I can't seem to figure it out. I am trying to flip my submarine on its y axis once its goes upside-down. it rotates on my mouse position.

This code rotates my submarine on mouse position which is perfect.

```
Vector3 RayPos = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
Vector3 dir = Input.mousePosition - RayPos;
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, 
rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);[sub flipping y][1]
```

Now this code is my problem. Once my sub goes upside down it flips (y) but 
  it only does it once and then when I go back the correct way it won't flip 
  on (y) anymore.

```
Debug.Log(Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Dot(transform.up, Vector3.up)));
if (Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Dot(transform.up, Vector3.down)) < 0.125f)
{
    if (Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Dot(transform.right, Vector3.down)) > 0.825f)
    {
        SubTrans.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, -1, 
        transform.localScale.z);
    }
    else
    {
        SubTrans.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, 1, 
        transform.localScale.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the second time you are asking this question. You are not getting answers because it is hard to understand your problem. Maybe you should show animated gif of what the problem looks like.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if (Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Dot(transform.up, Vector3.down)) < 0.125f)
> ```

I assume this makes your code perform the swap only when the sub is ~90 deg to the ground. This is fine because the absolute value means it occurs on both left & right sides.

> ```
>    if (Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Dot(transform.right, Vector3.down)) > 0.825f)
> ```

However this is wrong because of the absolute value. It treats up & down the same (comparatively since you're using transform.right), meaning it always flips you because abs(transform.right) is always >0.8 when the previous condition is valid.

You should be checking whether the sub is pointing up or down by checking the up direction like this

```
if (Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Dot(transform.up, Vector3.up)) > 0f) //less than 90deg angle with up
//flip sub upwards
else
//flip downwards
```

You can keep the outer if conditional if you want it to flip at certain times, but this is all that's needed.